# dynamic max-height on scrollable div based on window size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to achieve a div that has an auto max height so that when the list within the div is really long, it does not force the entire page to scroll, but instead extends its height to as far low as it can without making the page scroll, and have a scrollbar within the div itself. Currently, it is set with max-height of 800px. This should be autoset depending in browser viewport resolution.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vt2tvVAErdpmPRkg1txd?p=preview

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
 <div class="panel panel-body panel-primary">
 MainContent
 </div>
   </div> <!-- /.col-md-8 -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
            <div data-spy="affix">
           some list here
            <div style="max-height:800px;
overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; margin-top: 5px">
                <div class="panel panel-body panel-default">


                         another list here, but this div should have an auto max height so that when the list is really long, it does not force the entire page to scroll, but instead extends its height to as far low as it can without making the page scroll, and have a scrollbar within the div itself. Currently, it is set with max-height of 800px. This should be autoset depending in browser viewport size. 
                    </br>

                    </br>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so in your plnkr, I can not see your bootstrap col-md-x classes applying on the DIVs (I dont know why?).
But any ways, you want to keep your affix in the right side of the page with 4 column width. Well, in that condition you should check the browser height on load and resize event of the browser, and then put the max-height accordingly. This max-height should not contain the margins of the DIV.affix.

well, code should be like:

```
function setMaxheight(){
    var affixEle = $(">div", ".affix").first(),
        winHeight = $(window).height();

    // If there is some margins from top or bottom, remove it like:
    // winheight -= 20;

    affixEle.css({
        'max-height' : winHeight + "px"
    });
}

$(function(){
    setMaxheight();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        setMaxheight();
    });
});
```

CSS should be:

```
.affix > div{
    margin-top: 5px;
    overflow: auto; /*You dont need to put overflow-y or something. overflow:auto works perfectly*/
}
```

Comment: I believe it is working, but only after resizing the browser does the max-height kick in. On load, there is no scrolling available.

Comment: ok i removed affix and now the max height gets set perfectly on load of page. For some reason, affix does not kick in until you do something on the page like resize.

Comment: Ok it works now. The affix class doesn't get applied until you actually scroll or do something on the page, so calling affix > div doesn't work until that point. I used the approach of calling the div id "scroll" instead of using class selector. Now it works on page load. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
jquery:

   var divHeight=$(window).height()*62/100; 
   $("divid").css("max-height",divHeight);

javascript:

   var w = window.innerWidth;
   w=w*62/100;
   document.getElementById("p1").style.maxHeight=w+"px";
```

Comment: not sure how you would implement this, could you update the plnkr?

Comment: are using script or not if you use after using external js put inside of <script>above code</script>